# Nanograd differentation; what is going inside the python code

Tags: python, machine-learning, differentiation

I am reading up on deep learning and I am trying to understand the backpropagation methods in python nanograd.

See; https://github.com/rasmusbergpalm/nanograd

This is a method for computing the gradient, however I cannot seem to decode what is going on here. Can anyone help me understand this? Maybe by running through a very simple example. I have worked with recursive functions in Python before but this one is very difficult for me to decode.

The core of the code is;

```
def backprop(self, bp):
    self.grad += bp
    for parent, grad in self.parents:
        parent.backprop(grad * bp)

def backward(self):
    self.backprop(1.0)
```

Comment: Naming and convention are a bit strange. `bp` is the gradient that is to be propagated backwards, `grad` is the transpose of the (partial) node Jacobian (relating the output to the `parent` input).